# ExpandableListView в Android

Tags: android, java

Доброго времени суток!

Создаю `ExpandableListView` с кастомным адаптером:
Для `Child`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border_one_task"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox_task"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_task_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Задача1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="28sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_task_date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="10.12.2014"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#0000ff" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageview_task_map"
                android:layout_width="25sp"
                android:layout_height="25sp"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_mapmode" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Проблема заключается в том, что не могу обработать нажатие на child. Обычный 
    **setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener()...**
не срабатывает. Помогите, может кто-то сталкивался.

Comment: поправил ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не могу определить, почему не срабатывает `OnChildClickListener`, но могу посоветовать костыль. 
В `getchildview` выставить `OnClickListenner` вашему `childView`

Проверьте, не перехватывает ли сам `ExpandableListView` клики. То есть, может у него выставлено свойство focusable или clickable в true

Извиняюсь, забыл уже, как работать с ExpandableListView  
Переопределите `isChildSelectable` так:

```
@Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }
```

Этот метод определяет, является ли конкретный Child кликабельным. Если вернуть true, то `OnChildClickListener` вызовется.

**UPD**  
Оказалось, что ваш CheckBox перебирал на себя все события кликов. Что бы этого избежать нужно добавить чекбоксу атрибут

```
android:focusable="false"
```

Comment: @metalurgus, в том то и дело, что ничего такого не установлено. Пошарила на stackoverflow, оказалось что не у меня одной такие проблемы, но решения так никто и не сказал...

Comment: @metalurgus, вот блин не работает так)) может вы еще чего-нибудь важного забыли?)

Comment: @Мария_1 эх... придется создавать проект, и пробовать...

Comment: @metalurgus, Ура!)) безумно благодарна вам!) :)